# Sequentially running multiple python programs "with sys" using batch

Tags: python, batch-file, batch-processing

I am using Windows based PC.

I have multiple python programs with "sys". I mean the programs have these lines.

```
import sys
input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]
```

So I run these programs by running

```
python program1.py input1 output1
```

However, there are series of python programs so it will be convenient if I can run all these by double-clicking only one file.

How can I run them all sequentially, not simultaneously?

I tried things like

```
start C:\python27\python.exe program1.py input1 output1
start C:\python27\python.exe program2.py input2 output2
```

But it did not work..

Comment: try `call` instead of `start`

Comment: @MarkSetchell  behzad.nouri 's solution worked. But I am curious about your solution, too. By "Try start /wait", what code changes are you recommending?

Comment: I stepped away from my Mac but @Mofi has done a fine job of explaining it below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) is mainly for calling a batch file from within a batch file or running a block in current batch file as subroutine.

[Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) is the command to start any application as a separate process which means for a console applications to run it in a separate command prompt (console) window. A GUI application executed from within a batch file is always started as a separate process even if command **start** is not used.

Running an application results in halting the execution of the batch file until the application terminates itself for most applications. (There are applications with a different behavior caused by the application itself.) But a console or GUI application started using command **start** results in immediate continuation of batch file execution.

With using `start /wait ...` it is possible to start a console or GUI application as a separate process and halt execution of the batch file until the application terminates itself.

```
start /wait C:\python27\python.exe program1.py input1 output1
start /wait C:\python27\python.exe program2.py input2 output2
```

On running `start /?` in a command prompt window, the help for this command is printed into the output window.

`["title"]` means that optionally a title can be set for the new command prompt window (used only on starting a console application). I mention this here because command **start** can interpret any string in double quotes anywhere on the command line also as window title. Therefore if the application to start or one of its parameters must be enclosed in double quotes because of a space character or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` in path or file name, it is better to explicitly specify a title string in double quotes immediately after command **start** as first parameter which can be even an empty string like `""` (best for GUI applications).

```
start "Python Task 1" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" program1.py input1 output1
start "Python Task 2" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" program2.py input2 output2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your correct and detailed answer! I finally checked it works for running python programs sequentially. But I still could not find out how I can use this for running matlab and python sequentially. It just at least "opens" matlab.exe. But it does not "run" the mfile.

Comment: Mofi, your solution was very helpful for both python and matlab m-file. Can the batch file run it, in a way that m-file executed later can use variables made by m-file executed earlier? I explained the question in more detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631247/running-multiple-m-files-by-batch-on-windows-os-without-closing-previously-run

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.system('python' + ' ' + 'python_1.py')

os.system('python' + ' ' + 'python_2.py')
```

This solution is itself a python program. You can also construct the program names and have this in a loop. You can also add a parameter after the program name.

Comment: for what reason don't you do `os.system('python python_1.py')`?