# Running multiple m-files by batch on Windows OS "without" closing previously run m-file

Tags: python, matlab, batch-file, batch-processing

My purpose is to sequentially running a series of m-file and python programs.

And thanks to Mofi, Shai, and moarningsun, I could find out that this batch file is successful on my Windows OS:

```
start "01" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -wait -r "aatest1; exit;"
start "02" /wait "C:\python27\python.exe" python.py input.xlsx
start "03" /wait "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\bin\matlab.exe" -wait -r "aatest2; exit;"
```

It will run `aatest1.m`, then `python.py`, then `aatest2.m`.

However, since this closes MATLAB after running `aatest1.m`, `aatest2.m` cannot use the variables made by `aatest1.m`.

How can I code the batch so that `aatest2.m` can use the variables made from `aatest1.m`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1:

You can [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) all the relevant variables to a mat file at the end of `aatest1` and [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) them at the begining of `aatest2`.

#### Option 2:

You can run your python script in matlab (without terminating `aatest1`).
Use matlab's [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command to run the python script **in Matlab**:

```
[status,cmdout] = system( 'C:\python27\python.exe python.py input.xlsx' );
```

Comment: Option 2 was fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Shai, I wrote a very much related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695454/showing-or-leaving-python-error-messages-when-running-them-by-batch . Could you have a look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to write the names of the variables and their values you want to pass from `aatest1.m` to `aatest2.m` into a file in a format like:

```
variable1=value
variable2=value
```

`aatest1.m` creates this file with the names of the variables and their values, and `aatest2.m` reads the values from the file and initializes with those values the appropriate variables.

The batch file can finally after execution of `aatest2.m` delete the temporary used file to pass values of variables from one MATLAB script to next MATLAB script if there is no MATLAB function to delete a file directly from within `aatest2.m`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll remove the comment. I'd suggest to edit the answer so that it's more clear that the *MATLAB scripts* are responsible for the file creation/deletion, not the batch file. And MATLAB is perfectly capable of creating/deleting files and has its own format (`save`/`load`), so it's not necessary to invent and parse a custom format.